# How to read next word or words till next line from file in python?

Tags: python, file-io

i'm trying to read words from a line after matching words :

To be exact -
I have a file with below texts:

```
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Nov 15, 2006 at 09:58 AM
-- Server version: 5.0.21
-- PHP Version: 5.1.2
```

I want to search that, if that file contains 'Server version:' sub string, if do then read next characters after 'Server version:' till next line, in this case '5.0.21'.

I tried the following code, but it gives the next line(-- PHP Version: 5.1.2) instead of next word (5.0.21).

```
with open('/root/Desktop/test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Server version:' in line:
            print f.next()
```

Comment: Since according to your comments, the below answers helped you, why don't you accept one? I think you even had one accepted already, but then unaccepted it again -- why?

Comment: I thought all correct answers could be accepted but when i chose, the previous one get unaccepted, & since i'm new, i don't have enough reputation to vote up also. but i tried below answers and it worked so thank u all to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using f.next() which will return the next line.
Instead you need:

```
with open('/root/Desktop/test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        found = line.find('Server version:')
        if found != -1:
            version = line[found+len('Server version:')+1:]
            print version
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to replace that text like this

```
if 'Server version: ' in line:
    print line.rstrip().replace('-- Server version: ', '')
```

We do `line.rstrip()` because the read `line` will have a new line at the end and we strip that.

Comment: @tobias_k We can replace that as well. I updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `split` method on strings, using the string to remove (i.e. `'Server version: '`) as separator:

```
if 'Server version: ' in line:
    print line.split('Server version: ', 1)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be overkill, but you could also use the [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) module `re`:

```
match = re.search("Server version: (.+)", line)
if match:                # found a line matching this pattern
    print match.group(1) # whatever was matched for (.+ )
```

The advantage is that you need to type the key only once, but of course you can have the same effect by wrapping any of the other solutions into a function definition. Also, you could do some additional validation.

Answer (score 0):

as you have

```
line='-- Server version: 5.0.21'
```

just:

```
line.split()[-1]
```

This gives you the last word rather than all the characters after `:`.

If you want all the characters after `:`

```
line.split(':', 1)[-1].strip()
```

Replace `:` with other string as needed.

Comment: Won't work for `Generation time`, though... alternatively, what about `split': ')`?

Comment: @tobias_k the OP question was for Server Version.